# Pagination gives wrong links for category blog layout

Tags: php, joomla, pagination, joomla2.5

I am running Joomla 2.5, and have made no changes to core joomla code. I have a menu item pointing to a category blog layout (stock joomla), which the url looks like:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=83&Itemid=446
```

However the pagination links make no sense:

```
index.php?option=com_content&view=article&layout=blog&Itemid=481&catid=83&limitstart=1
```

As you can see there are several things wrong with these links:

- the view is wrong, now article rather than category,
- id is specified as catid,
- itemid is wrong (this is the itemid of the front page, not the one from my menu item!).
- Following this link results in a 404, with "Article not found" message.

Any idea what is causing this and how to fix it? I am simply trying to achieve a paginated list of articles (with intro text) for a news section of my site.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: Does your template have a pagination.php file?

Comment: No, my template does not.

Comment: I just tried using pagination on the current master and I'm not getting that problem.  Are you talking about the  first/previous .. next/last or the numbers or both?

Comment: On all the pagination links i see the issue

Comment: Can you try copying the pagination.php file from protostar to your template?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're referring to with protostar?

Comment: The default template. Oh sorry, beez, forgot you were on 2.5.